# Why is my miniconda not usable as pycharm interpreter?

Tags: python, miniconda

I just created a (mini)conda env with a simple command

conda create MyNewEnv

MyNewEnv is created and I can activate and use it. So far so good.

Then I tried to use it as PyCharm interpreter but I realised that there were very few files/folders created under C:\users\eric\.conda\envs\MyNewEnv

I just have one folder "conda-meta" while my other environments have far more.

[image]

I believe I also created these other environments with the same command (conda create whatever)

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: You can [configure a current conda virtual environment or create a new one directly in PyChram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html). Did you follow the steps in the documentation?

Comment: No I did not... I just created a new environment from the miniconda command line... but I had done the same for the others since I only installed pycharm very recently

Comment: But I could try as documented in pycharm indeed... I'll try that!

Comment: "Then I tried to use it as PyCharm interpreter but I realised that there were very few files/folders created under C:\users\eric\.conda\envs\MyNewEnv" - okay, but did this actually prevent you from using it as the interpreter in PyCharm? Did you get any kind of error message? Did the code not run, or run with a different interpreter? What is the actual diagnostic here?

Comment: I could not select it as an interpreter in PyCharm because there was no python executable to select

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9177877/it-is-chris . I removed my environment and recreated it using pycharm and everything is now fine.